# Why I am getting a warning message when displaying XML, can I remove it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am getting the following warning message, What is the best solution to remove these warning messages?

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

I am returning data in JSON format

```
 string JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtbrands);
 return JSONresult;
```

Comment: Usually you may simply ignore it. For which file do you get the warning?

Comment: I have requirement to remove it....do I have any way to remove it???

Answer (score 0):

It's just a feature of your browser.  When you request an XML file direct, the XML can specify an XSLT (the "style") which the browser can use to render html from the xml.  If there is no link to an XSLT then then browser has no option but to show you the raw XML which is probably what you're seeing.

Comment: JSF? We´re talking ASP here.